# Upgrading to graphql-js 15.0.0 breaks working configuration with message: Field "[...]" already exists in the schema

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I am working on an app that is operating fine with `14.6.0`, but throws an error message when upgrading `graphql` to `15.0.0`. Before getting to the error message, let's walk through the configuration:

Here's how I'm initializing the app:

```
export default new ApolloServer({
    schema: makeExecutableSchema({
        typeDefs,
        resolvers: merge(...resolverObjects),
    })
});
```

...where:

- `typeDefs` is an array made up of the plaintext content of `.graphql` files read from the disk (the app is doing different things so I've logically separated the schema into multiple files).
- `merge` is the `lodash` function that does a deep merge on all `resolverObjects`.

The first schema in `typeDefs` is a dummy "base" schema:

```
type Query {
    _dummy: String
}

type Mutation {
    _dummy: String
}
```

All the subsequent schemas define new object types and extend the `Query` and/or `Mutation` schemas:

```
extend type Query {
    readStuff: String!
}

extend type Mutation {
    saveStuff: Boolean!
}
```

In `14.6.0`, this setup works fine.

Upgrading to `15.0.0` produces the following error, for every new property of the extended Query and Mutation types:

```
Field "[...]" already exists in the schema. It cannot also be defined in this type extension.
```

But it does not already exist. It's only defined in type extensions. What's the problem?

Comment: Could be an issue with the version of graphql-tools you are using. Is `makeExecutableSchema` imported from `apollo-server` or `graphql-tools`? What version of the library are you using?

Comment: `ApolloServer` and `makeExecutableSchema` are both imported from `apollo-server-express`.

Comment: Your comment made me look into the dependencies of `apollo-server-express`. It depends on version `4` of `graphql-tools`, while the latest version is `6`. Adding an explicit dependency on `graphql-tools` version `6` and importing `makeExecutableSchema` from there produces a working configuration, with `graphql` version `15`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Daniel Rearden who commented on the original question, I got to the bottom of it. The problem was that I was importing `makeExecutableSchema` from `apollo-server-express`, which depends on `graphql-tools` version `4`.

The latest `graphql-tools` is version `6`. Adding an explicit dependency on this latest version and importing `makeExecutableSchema` from it allowed me to upgrade to the latest `graphql` version (`15.0.0`).